# Unit Testing Node JS API using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write unit test cases for NodeJS API by mocking the DB call using `jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(["FAQ 1"]));`

**My API factory file is something like this:**

```
const getFAQ=(request,reply)=>{

faqs.findByCondition(request.params.filter,success=>{
    reply(Response.sendResponse(true, success, ResponseMessages.SUCCESS, StatusCodes.OK));
 }, error => {
    log.error('ERROR : ', error);
         reply(Response.sendResponse(false, error, ResponseMessages.ERROR, 400));
    });

};
```

**My Model JS containing `findByCondition()` is something like this:**

```
findByCondition = (condition, success_callback, error_callback) => {
        "use strict";
        faq.find(condition, (err, docs) => {
            if (err) {
                error_callback(err);
            } else {
                success_callback(docs);
            }
        });
    }
```

**I've tried writing my unit test case as follows:**

```
describe("test cases for FAQ Factory", () => {
    utils.callAPI = jest.fn(() => 'test')

    test('getFAQ Success Case', (done) => {
        const request = {
            params: {
                filter: 'all'
            },
            headers: {
                authorization: 'asfasfasdfas'
            }
        }
        faqModel.findByCondition = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(["FAQ 1"]));
        faqFactory.getFAQ(request, (result) => {
            expect(result).toBeDefined();
            expect(result.status_code).toBe(200);
        })
    })
});
```

I'm able to run the test case successfully but the code coverage is not covering the success or error callbacks

**but the same test case works if I change my API Factory to something like this:**

```
const getFAQ = (request, reply) => {
  faqs.findByCondition(request.params.filter).then(success => {
    reply(Response.sendResponse(true, success, ResponseMessages.SUCCESS, StatusCodes.OK));
  }).catch(error => {

    log.error('ERROR : ', error);
    reply(Response.sendResponse(false, error, ResponseMessages.ERROR, 400));
  });
};
```

Is there any way that I could write my test case so that it will cover the success/error callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I have found a solution by using mockingoose library, writing my test case as follows:

```
test("test to getFAQ Success", async (done) => {
        const request = {
            params: {
                filter: 'all'
            },
            headers: {
                authorization: testData.authorization
            }
        }
        mockingoose(faqModel.faq).toReturn([], 'find');
        const result = await promisify(faqFactory.getFAQ, request);
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
        expect(result.status).toEqual(200);
        done();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to have the `findByCondition` to be overwritten if you want to test both cases and pass your callback to `getFAQ`

I've simplified it a little to make it clearer what I mean.

```js
const getFAQ = (request, reply) => {
  faqs
    .findByCondition(request.params.filter)
    .then(success => {
      reply(true);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reply(false);
    });
};

const faqs = {
  findByCondition: () => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
};

it("works", () => {
  jest.spyOn(faqs, `findByCondition`).mockResolvedValue({});
  getFAQ({ params: { filter: "hello" } }, reply => {
    expect(reply).toBe(true);
  });
});

it("doesn't work", () => {
  jest.spyOn(faqs, `findByCondition`).mockRejectedValue(new Error(`This fails because of error`));
  getFAQ({ params: { filter: "hello" } }, reply => {
    expect(reply).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

You can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-ffqds)

Comment: Yeah.. this solution works. But I'm not allowed to change the actual ```findbyCondition() ``` in factory

Comment: you don't have to, you can just overwrite it by `jest.spyOn....`
I just made the `findByCondition` because I needed the reference

Comment: I have overwritten the functions in the test file and it works. But, When I see my code coverage report generated for the factory, I can see that the code factory code is not covered as we have overwritten the same in our test file.
Is there any other way we could modify our test case for code coverage?